# Drupal: how to access to Drupal's APIs with a standalone php script?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

When I create a new script in a separate php file to run for Drupal, I need to add the following lines on top in order to access all Drupal APIs:

require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

Is this correct ?

Comment: It's easy enough to test it yourself. What happens when you do that?

Comment: @Mark Trapp You know, sometimes you load more stuff than necessary, even if it works

Comment: Take a look at update.php. I think it runs without a full bootstrap. You might get some hints there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep, I use this:

```
/** bootstrap drupal **/
chdir("/path/to/drupal/site/htdocs");
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

And then just add whatever Drupal-specific code you need below that.

Comment: Also, check the documentation of drupal_bootstrap to see which bootstrap level you actually need.

Comment: The question was about accessing "all Drupal APIs" - is it really THAT simple, or do dependencies rear their ugly head? Example: using Drupal Forms API in an external PHP script (because FAPI is awesome). 

Not for lack of trying, but I haven't found any blog posts demonstrating Drupal API usage outside of Drupal. If anyone has such links, it's on-topic and much appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 5):

this method still works with drupal 7, but instead of the chdir bit you may need to add the following line before the require and bootstrap call:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT','/path/to/drupal');
```

Comment: or define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd())

Answer (score 2):

This should work for both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 :

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', 'path/to/drupal');
chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT);
require './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

It doesn't matter where you put the script that contains this code. Just make sure you replace `path/to/drupal` with the actual installation path of your Drupal system.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's one way to enter drupal api.
 Sometime `chdir("dir to drupal dir");` required, if you call php script from other directory.