# How to create a drupal user with out email address?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, registration

I want to create a Drupal user account without an email address. How can I create that? If I write a custom query which tables do I have to insert values in? Or does Drupal have a built-in function for that?

I have only user's first name, last name, password details. I want to create a user with only this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, even email is required:

```
$newUser = array(
  'name' => 'your username',
  'pass' => 'any password', // note: do not md5 the password
  'status' => 1,
);           
user_save(null, $newUser);
```

Comment: Hi user_save(null, $newUser);  return any thing. How can we Identify the data is saved or not?

Comment: I need the userid for some other functionality creation

Comment: the created user object is returned

Comment: Hi how can I call this function from civicrm like external modules

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014244/drupal-how-to-access-to-drupals-apis-with-a-standalone-php-script