# How to Use Drupal Search In Standalone PHP Page?

Tags: search, drupal, indexing, bootstrapping

I followed the instructions @ [Drupal: how to access to Drupal's APIs with a standalone php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014244/) , however, my search query is returning 0 results (an empty array). I have confirmed that the same search term returns a result if executed from my drupal web page.

```
<?php
    chdir("drupal");
    define("DRUPAL_ROOT",".");
    require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
    include 'drupal/modules/search/search.api.php';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
    $keys = array("harry","potter");
    $result = hook_search_execute($keys);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Can anyone give me some pointers as to why this isn't working? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `hook_search_execute` directly--this is only meant for API documentation.

So, no need to include search.api.php. Instead, take a look at [`search_data()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/function/search_data/7), which calls a specific module (user module, or node module, for example) invoking that hook. If you are trying to search nodes, you can call [`node_search_execute()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_search_execute/7) directly.