# how to get info from drupal database

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am new to drupal and I want to see the logged in user name and his email address in a phpscript which is not in drupal installation. 
Any idea how would I go about it. Using drupal 6.2

tried this already

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/bootstrap.inc';
require_once 'includes/common.inc';
require_once 'includes/module.inc';

global $user; 
if ($user->uid) 
{ 
$name=$user->name; 
echo $name; 
}

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is hook your standalone script into Drupal's bootstrapping mechanism. [Here's a SO question that shows how to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014244/drupal-how-to-access-to-drupals-apis-with-a-standalone-php-script)

Then, your global $user solution will work.