# Calling Drupal functions in external PHP file

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, global-variables, external

How can I call a Drupal function or get the global variable in a PHP file which is located under the drupal installation folder. I doing it for the first time. Are there any files I need to include in my code in order to access the Drupal function or variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014244/drupal-how-to-access-to-drupals-apis-with-a-standalone-php-script

Comment: I strongly recmmend that you consider writing a module instead of adding arbitrary PHP files for things that should be part of the website. And for scripts, you can write drush scripts (http://drupal.org/project/drush).

Comment: @Berdir I am using it for testing purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Taken from the linked question in the comment above*

You need to Bootstrap Drupal in the external PHP file:

```
/** bootstrap Drupal **/
chdir("/path/to/drupal/site/htdocs");
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Be sure to change the path to your Drupal installation, then add your code below the code posted above.

Answer (score 10):

If the above explained example doesn't work try this:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
chdir($path."/drupal");
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd()); //the most important line
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Comment: this looks like a hybrid of both drupal 6 and drupal 7

Comment: How do we do for Drupal8?

Answer (score 2):

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

The above code works for me, when the script is in my Drupal root directory. This loads absolutely everything, not just Drupal core, including contributed module hooks.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
global $user;
print_r($user);
```

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer. If your answer is an improvement, you should add some detail explaining why.