# How can I display user avatar by knowing user ID(uid) in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, uid

I want to display user picture if the user id is known. Is possible to do it without using additional modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the user id you want to get the picture of you can use [`user_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_load/6).  user_load() will load a user object full of a user's information.  To find the structure of the user object, you can use `print_r()`.

Example for Drupal 6:

```
<?php
  $account = user_load(10);
  print theme('image', $account->picture, 'User Avatar', $account->name . "'s Avatar");
?>
```

There is also more you can do with [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_image/6), like adding attributes to the img tag, etc.

If you are looking for the picture of the currently logged in user, you don't even need to use `user_load()` or the uid, simply do the following:

```
<?php
  global $user;
  print theme('image', $user->picture, 'User Avatar', $user->name . "'s Avatar");
?>
```

These examples were for Drupal 6 (since no version was specified) but there are only slight changes for Drupal 7.

Comment: Thank you for response. Now I'm starting to understand how the the things work. But if i want to display the list of user avatars? And I don't want to use theme function. I want to send image to the template file. What should i do? P.S. I'm working with drupal 7

Comment: Send from .module to .php.tpl file. Template file gets info from module file. That's why i said that. I don't want to use Views. I want to do everything by my own module without external ones.

Comment: If you want to send information from a module to a `.tpl` file you will have to use `hook_theme()`: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6

Comment: I managed to display user image in Drupal 7 using: <?php print theme('user_picture', array('account' =>user_load(1)));?> But how can i change style of the image? (e.g. change the size of the avatar)? And how can i display other parameters (uid, name and other items of user table)?

Comment: Use the `$user` variable to show other user information, ie `print $user->uid; print $user->name;` etc.  If you are looking to change the size of the image and are _set_ on using `theme_user_picture()` (which really just uses `theme_image()` unless have image module) you can override `template_preprocess_user_picture()`: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/template_preprocess_user_picture/7  in your template.php

Comment: Ok thank you for response. I did it in this way: $account = user_load(1); print '<img src="http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/pictures/'.$account->picture->filename.'" alt="'.$account->name.'" width="auto"; height="50px" />';}

Comment: Now i have another problem. I want to get acces to the drupal function from external php file: $account = user_load(1) But i got the error: Call to undefined function user_load(). How can i use this function in the external file?

Comment: If you are going to do it that way, you should just do `$account = user_load(1); $variables = array('path' => 'sites/default/files/pictures/'.$account->picture->filename', 'width' => 'auto', 'height' => '50px', 'alt' => $account->name); print theme('image', $variables);`

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517813/calling-drupal-functions-in-external-php-file for the answer to your other question.  Please do not ask more than one question per "question".