# How to hash a password using function <user_hash_password>

Tags: php, hash, drupal-7, password-encryption

I am not a professional developer so my question might sound dumb, sorry for that,

I am making an android app which connects to a database of users whose passwords are stored in 
hashed format, so I donno how to include this function [user_hash_password](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7) in my php file so I can hash the inputted password and then match it with the ones in the database, I think you can help me learn that. By the way the passwords already stored, are hashed with the same function.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help :)

```
 <?php

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $database = "android";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $localhost = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
    or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
    mysql_select_db($database, $localhost);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    $query = "select * from drupal_users where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";
    $query_exec = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
    if($rows == 0) {
    echo "No user was found";

    }else {
    echo "User found";
    }

  ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Comment: Hashing your password is useless if you leave your DB open to injections

Comment: He is obviously is new at this, remind yourself he is asking a legit question albeit not showing a lot of effort.  @Moeen could you share what you tried before.  The idea of your hashing function is it hashes passwords when saving it to DB and when a user inputs his/her password.  So you need to hash the `$_POST['password']` with the same method you stored them with. This way you can actually compare them.

Comment: @timmied, you're right, I want to hash $_POST['password'], I just don't know how to use the function user_hash_password, I put the link of this function in my question, I searched a lot to find an example of using this function but I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to hash the `$_POST['password']` with the same method you stored them with.

Just like this:

```
$password =  user_hash_password($_POST['password']);
```

You do however need to include the drupal file (`includes/password.inc`) containing this method.

If your creating an external php file and not a drupal module you should try to research how to include your function.

[Calling Drupal functions in external PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517813/calling-drupal-functions-in-external-php-file)

[Drupal: how to access to Drupal's APIs with a standalone php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014244/drupal-how-to-access-to-drupals-apis-with-a-standalone-php-script)

Or you can reverse engineer the hashing method by just recreating it and looking up needed variables / constants.

In this case `DRUPAL_HASH_COUNT`.

Answer (score 0):

First Save Password in Database in md5(password). Than while fetching use

```
> $query = "select * from drupal_users where username = '".$username."'
> AND password = '".md5($password)."'";
```

Comment: Don't use md5, use a better hashing algorithm, a salt and multiple repetitions. Also, it OP wants to use the function he linked, not another one

Comment: I think I said with which function I want to hash, I didnt talk about md5 dude